# How to get pixel range in scaled canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In the following code, I am drawing a circle on the center, but because it is scaled, the circle is in bottom right corner!

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.canvas.width = 400;
context.canvas.height = 200;

context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

var scale = 2;
context.scale(scale, scale);
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = "#ff2626"; // Red color
context.arc(context.canvas.width / 2, context.canvas.height / 2, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2); //center
context.fill();
context.closePath();
```

```css
canvas {
 border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
<body>

<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>

</body>
</HTML>
```

As you probably know, canvas width and height is not related to what is drawing inside it, especially when you scale it. in other word, when you scale a canvas using `context.scale(scale_x, scale_y);` it will scale all shapes inside the canvas. I am wondering to know, is there any way to get the canvas pixel range?

I want to know the X on left edge and right edge and the Y on top and bottom edges when a canvas is scaled.

Comment: Since you scale by 2 have you tried to center it considering the scale? Like (width*scale)/2 to get the scaled center? Try that let me know!

Comment: @MadeInDreams I really know how to centralize it using scale attribute, but the problem is that I found the X and Y will change in a scaled canvas. It was long story, but I need corners of canvas really, not the center.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing the coordinates by `scale` should do the trick:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.canvas.width = 400;
context.canvas.height = 200;

context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

var scale = 2;
context.scale(scale, scale);
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = "#ff2626"; // Red color
context.arc(context.canvas.width /2/scale, context.canvas.height / 2/scale, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2); //center
context.fill();
context.closePath();
```

```css
canvas {
 border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
<body>

<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>

</body>
</HTML>
```

And on a side note, `context.canvas.width /(2*scale)` is cleaner than `context.canvas.width /2/scale`, but I kept it like that just to show the division by `scale`.

Comment: Then you mean left-top corner now is 0 and 0?

Comment: top-left corner is always (0,0), regardless of the scale (unless you did sonme `translate` operation).

Comment: And in general, all coordinates should now be divided by the scale

Comment: Then, maybe it is better to ask, if I translate canvas to center, then scale it, what is the edge pixels?

Comment: Then I need to show you something, because I found the corners are not scaled exactly in the way they should

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this pixel range.

You have to understand how canvas transformations work and embrace it rather than trying to do the math yourself.

If we take the canvas as a real canvas, or as a sheet of paper, then we can say that the transformation matrix controls the position of this sheet of paper relative to a fixed camera.

The key point is that, the coordinates you provide to the canvas *drawing methods* are still the ones that are on the un-transformed sheet of paper, no matter how you did rotate, translate or scale it.

Also, initially, we do hold this sheet of paper by its top left corner, this is known as the *transformation-origin*; all the transformations like rotate and scale will be done from this point, and this is why when you did scale by 2, the center coordinates are now in the bottom right corner of what the camera sees.

So if you wish to scale to the center of your canvas, you need to first move the *transformation-origin* so it's at the center of our camera, then you can scale your canvas, and finally you just go back again by half the size of the canvas so your drawings are in the center. This can be achieved quite easily by two calls: one to the absolute [`setTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform), which is able to apply both the scaling and the initial translation required to set our transformation origin, and one to [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate), which is relative to the current transform matrix:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

const scale = 2;
const cx = canvas.width / 2;
const cy = canvas.height / 2;

// before transformation in red
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc( cx, cy, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();

// with transformation in semi-opaque green
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
// scale with origin set to the center of canvas
ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, cx, cy);
// move back origin to the new top left corner of the visible area
ctx.translate( -cx, -cy );

/* the two previous lines are effectively the same as
  ctx.translate( cx, cy );
  ctx.scale( scale, scale );
  ctx.translate( -cx, -cy );
and as 
  ctx.setTransform(
    scale, 0, 0,
    scale, cx - (cx * scale) , cy - (cy * scale)
  );
*/

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc( cx, cy, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

As you can already see in this little example, you are not limited to a single transformation matrix per frame, you can very well compose your image by layering a few different transformations:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
const { width, height } = canvas;
const cx = width / 2;
const cy = height / 2;

const transform = {
  angle: 0,
  scale: 1,
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

const img = new Image();
img.onload = anim;
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png";

function anim() {
  updateTransform();
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame( anim );
}
function updateTransform() {
  transform.x += Math.cos( transform.angle );
  transform.y += Math.sin( transform.angle );
  transform.scale = (Math.sin( transform.angle ) / 3) + 1;
  transform.angle += Math.PI / 180;
}

function draw() {
  // reset the transformation matrix
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, width, height );
  
  drawImage();
  
  drawCircleOnImage();
  
  drawCentralSquare();
  
  drawCameraCross();
}

// the image is moved by our 'tranform' object
function drawImage() {
  ctx.setTransform( transform.scale, 0, 0, transform.scale, transform.x, transform.y );
  ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
}

// A circle which will be moved with the image
function drawCircleOnImage() {
  ctx.setTransform( transform.scale, 0, 0, transform.scale, transform.x, transform.y );
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc( cx, cy, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2 );
  ctx.stroke()
}


// a square, always at the center of view,
// but which scale follows our transform object
function drawCentralSquare() {
  ctx.setTransform( transform.scale, 0, 0, transform.scale, cx, cy );
  ctx.translate( -cx, -cy );
  ctx.strokeRect( cx - 50, cy - 50, 100, 100 );
}

// a cross, always at the center of the view, and untransformed
function drawCameraCross() {
  ctx.setTransform( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 );
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo( cx - 10, cy );
  ctx.lineTo( cx + 10, cy );
  ctx.moveTo( cx, cy - 10 );
  ctx.lineTo( cx, cy + 10 );
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

And this with no maths from our part.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but is there any way to get the range?

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider your scale so ex (width/2)/scale

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.canvas.width = 400;
context.canvas.height = 200;

context.clearRect(context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

var scale = 2;
context.scale(scale, scale);
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = "#ff2626"; // Red color
context.arc((context.canvas.width/2)/scale , (context.canvas.height/2)/scale, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2); //center
context.fill();
context.closePath();
```

```css
canvas {
 border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
<body>

<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>

</body>
</HTML>
```